# /bin/bash: ./marian-decoder: No such file or directory in google colab

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a script in google colab using the command:

```
! cat data/newstest2015.deen.bpe.de \
| ./marian-decoder --models wmt16_systems/de-en/model.npz \
    --vocabs wmt16_systems/de-en/vocab.{de,en}.json --dim-vocabs 85000 85000 \
    --type amun --dim-emb 500 \
        > data/newstest2015.deen.bpe.out
```

but I am getting this error:  `/bin/bash: ./marian-decoder: No such file or directory`. I have the script `marian-decoder` in that folder.

I also tried to add the full path to the script but didn't work.

Comment: What's the first line of `marian-decoder`? Does it point to an interpreter which is not installed on your system?

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting of your code but I had to guess some things. Please review.

Comment: Maybe also fix the [useless `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

Comment: Is it called `marian-decoder` or `marian-decoder.sh`?

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for fixing. The same command above works in my ubuntu terminal but not in google colab.

Comment: @BHC it is just `marian-decoder` and no .sh